# Can node keys that were pushed to GitHub before .env and .ignore files were created still be accessible?

Tags: node.js, git, gitignore

Before I created `.env` and `.gitignore` files I had a key `00000` inside my `app.js` file that was basically naked text (I forgot the slang word for it):

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    privateKey: 00000 // this key is naked
  })
});
```

I committed and pushed the `app.js` file up to GitHub `git push origin master` (*first commit*)

Later on I created a `.env` file to create a constant to hide my naked key:

```
PRIVATE_KEY=00000
```

Inside my `app.js` file I replaced the naked key with the constant from the `.env` file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY // the key is now safely hidden once added to the .gitignore file
  })
});
```

I create a `.gitignore` file, added the `.env` file to it, committed and pushed everything to Github (*second commit*)

**The question I have is now that my key is hidden, no one can access it, but what about the very first commit when I pushed everything and the key was naked, is that somehow accessible/unsafe?**

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fardjad sent me a link in the comments: [github sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)

It says:

> Warning: Once you have pushed a commit to GitHub, you should consider any data it contains to be compromised. If you committed a password, change it! If you committed a key, generate a new one.
>   This article tells you how to make commits with sensitive data unreachable from any branches or tags in your GitHub repository. However, it's important to note that those commits may still be accessible in any clones or forks of your repository, directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views on GitHub, and through any pull requests that reference them. You can't do anything about existing clones or forks of your repository, but you can permanently remove all of your repository's cached views and pull requests on GitHub by contacting GitHub Support.

The answer is YES the first commit with the naked text is accessible/unsafe.

Comment: As stated in the link above, any sensitive data posted to Github should be considered compromised; it's highly recommended that you generate a new key pair. In order to remove the current (compromised) key from previous commits, you can use [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). You need to save the key in a text file (ex. **keys.txt**), and run `bfg --replace-text keys.txt /path/to/your/repo`. After that you should be able to **force** push the (re-written) commits to GitHub (ie. `git push --force --all origin`)